# Error in reading the file in C

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I'm trying to write and read from file. writing works fine, but when it tries to read, the program crashed. tell me whats the error?

The objective of this program is to store the record of students in a file.
Calculate the percentage, and find the highest and lowest percentage of student.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct result
{
char name[15];
int batchNo;
int rgtNo;
int marks;
float perc;
};
int main()
{
    char answer, i = 1;
FILE *ptr, *abc;
result s, st;
int j;
ptr = fopen("rec.txt","a");
abc = fopen("rec.txt","r");
if(!ptr)
    printf("Error opening file");
else if(!abc)
    printf("Error opening read file");
else {
do
{
    int sum = 0;
    printf("\nEnter name of student %d: ", i);
    scanf("%s", s.name);
    printf("\nEnter Batch #: ");
    scanf("%d", &s.batchNo);
    printf("\nEnter Registeration no: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &s.rgtNo);
    printf("\nEnter marks of Five subjects: ");
    scanf("%d",&s.marks);
    /*for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&s.marks[j]);
        sum += s.marks[j];
    }*/
    s.perc = sum / 5.0;
    printf("Percentage of student %d: %f", i+1,  s.perc);
    fprintf(ptr, "%s %d %d %d %f", s.name, s.batchNo, s.rgtNo, s.marks, s.perc);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("Do you want to add another record? (y/n) ");
    answer = getche();
    i++;
} while(answer == 'y');

printf("outside loop\n");
fclose(ptr);
fflush(stdin);
rewind(abc);
do
{
    fscanf(abc, "%s%d%d%d%f", s.name, s.batchNo, s.rgtNo, s.marks, s.perc);
    printf("in loop");
} while( !feof(abc));
fclose(abc);
}


}
```

Comment: 'tell me whats the error?' Why don't you tell us what the error is, instead of us trying to guess? Then we can help you diagnose the error.

Comment: The program crashes with I enter NO (Y/N)

Comment: `ptr = fopen("rec.txt","a");abc = fopen("rec.txt","r");` --> `ptr = fopen("rec.txt","a+");`,

Answer (score 2):

So many defects, so little time.

**C is not C++**
They are two different languages.  Remove the C++ tag.
But since you tagged it as C++, you should use the `fstream` and `iostream` libraries as well as the `std::string` type.

**One pointer per physical file**
You have one `FILE *` for each different mode of the same file.  In many cases, this will confuse the operating system and heck some won't allow it.

Instead, use one `FILE *` and open the file as `rw+` for **read**, **write** and **append**.

See `fseek` function.

**Buffer overflow with scanf**
You have reserved 15 letters for the name.  What happens if the user types in a name longer than 15 letters?  Buffer overflow.  You could write over other variables that follow the `name` member.
You could resolve this by using `fscanf` with the C language or `std::cin` and `std::string` with the C++ language.

**Flushing the input**
The `flush` function only works with *output* buffers.  Don't use with input streams.
In the C language you have to read characters until the buffer is empty or until your terminator character is found (such as 'n').
In C++ this is accomplished by `cin.ignore(1000000, '\n')`.

**Checking input functions for errors**
You can't trust the User.  You **must** check the `scanf` return value for errors.  If you ask for a number and the User types in a number, the `scanf` will fail.  The value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

the program crashes whenever you type something different than 'y' at the last question `Do you want to add another record? (y/n)`.

think what happens after this stage in your program...

hint - take a look at your `ptr` and `abc` `File` pointers - do they point to the same file?

Answer (score 0):

The issue which makes your program segfault is the `fscanf` call: you're supposed to pass pointers to variables for arguments. I guess you quickly C&P without double checking your code.

As mentioned in another answer: `fflush` behaviour isn't specified for input streams, though many implementations behave as you expect. Another way to flush is to do a loop on the stream and read char by char:

```
void flush_stdin(){
  char c;
  while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    c = getchar();
}
```

Note: I'm using `getchar`, as `getche` isn't available on my system. I suppose you should have it too, and would recommend using it for portability.

Regarding multiple opening of the same file in different modes: I don't think it should be a problem, though it seems much more straightforward to open it in append mode first, close it when the input session is done, and then reopen it for reading afterwards. In a more complex program, you'd probably split these two functionalities in separate functions, each doing its own I/O, thus following that pattern.

One last thing: you probably want to test the result of your calls to `scanf` and the like. Perhaps a small macro like the following would help:

```
#define CHECK_SCAN(x) do {                          \
    int err = (x);                                  \
    if (err <= 0) {                                 \
      printf("error on scan: %s", strerror(err));   \
      exit(1);                                      \
    } } while(0)
```